# How can I convince my ASUS EEE B202 to boot, when the power is returned to its power supply

Tags: boot, power, eee-pc, acpi

My little home server 'sulks', when it loses power. Instead of booting, when the power is returned, it waits for me to press its power-button.

Is there a way to have it boot without human interaction?

(Asus EEE B202, 2GB Ram, 160GB disk, Ubuntu 9.10)

---

**SOLUTION** Based on U-D13's tip, so let him have the votes!

- When you power EEE-BOX up
- press the `<del>` key.
- select the **Power** Menu
- select the **APM Configuration** Sub-Menu
- select **Restore on AC Power Loss**
- your choices are

  - **Power Off** (default)
    This will keep the machine turned off when the mains power returns
  - **Power On**
    This will always power the machine on, when the mains power returns
  - **Last State** (this solved my problem)
     This will return the machine to the state it was in when the mains power went away. 
         If the machine was powered on, it will reboot when the mains power returns
         If the machine was powered off, it will stay off when the mains power returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the BIOS APM / ACPI (Power Management) settings.
According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Unattended_operation)

> ... It may be possible to set the BIOS to start [the machine] up automatically on restoration of power, so that it is never left in an unresponsive state. A typical BIOS setting is *AC back function* which may be *on*, *off*, or *memory*. *On* is the correct setting in this case ...

Comment: +1 I thought I'd searched the BIOS ... but a second persistant look showed that the EEE-BOX has an entry 'RESTORE on AC Power Loss'. I'll add that as solution to my question, you get the credit for solving. THANKS!

Comment: You're very welcome! At least I successfully pointed you the right direction (oh, what a feat.. ahem). But the collective success is still worth a "yay!"